# Telugu language in raspbian

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I installed ibus(m17n) and added a telugu input method. I also installed telugu font package(fonts-telu). But I am not able to use telugu(after selecting it in the task bar icon) input method in libreWriter. Can someone suggest what to do? I am very new to linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are referring to LibreOffice Writer. You need to install the Telugu package for LibreOffice. Open a terminal and paste or type this in:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-te
```

You may also be interested in some other Telugu packages that are available such as the list this creates:

```
apt search Telugu
```

Comment: But I want to be able to type in Telugu in other apps too like in text editor and browser. I want to know why the input method is not working.

Comment: Ok, so does ibus work other apps like your text editor and your browser or you don't have it working at all? Does it work with everything but LibreOffice? I'm not sure ibus works with LibreOffice. The instructions at the bottom of the ReadMe https://github.com/ibus/ibus/wiki/ReadMe show how to run it for GTK, KDE, and X apps, but nothing else. You may have to ask the ibus people directly.

Comment: I searched some more and found that LibreOffice should work with ibus, but it may take some extra configuration. Try the suggestions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#LibreOffice

Comment: It doesn't work on any app

Comment: Ok, when you said "I installed ibus(m17n) and added a telugu input method." I didn't realize those are actually two different things. Ibus runs as a daemon (program that runs in the background waiting for instructions. Installing it doesn't affect the taskbar icon for language selection. I'm not actually sure how to get ibus working or how the taskbar language icon works. I'll have to do some investigating.